# What is .struts-config.xml.strutsdia file?

Tags: java, configuration, struts, configuration-files

I am working on an old struts project and I found this file in the `WEB-INF` folder, does any one know what this file is, and if it has any useful info?

Comment: If you mean struts-config.xml - read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_configuration.htm)

Comment: no .... I know struts-config.xml well ..... I have been developing on struts for years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a metadata file used by JBoss Tools IDE (Eclipse) to draw diagrams in the Eclipse editor by the plugin using the source from the `struts-config.xml`.

This file is auto-generated, so you can delete it for free.

Comment: so .... what if I found something in this file (a certain action) that is not present in struts-config.xml ...... is there any possibility other than that something was removed from the struts-config.xml before the file is generated ???
another question .... does it rely only on struts-config.xml  to be generated , or it searches in the actions located in the jsps ?

Comment: yes, it searches JSPs under web root, if they could be accessed directly and generates web flow.

Comment: so if jsp points to an action that is not present in struts-config.xml (which is a bug) it can be found in the file.... right?

Comment: yes, it's possible in unsynchronized versions of this file and struts-config.